# Should [audiowaveform] tag be a (one-way) synonym of [waveform]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

There are 559 questions tagged [waveform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/waveform) and 19 questions tagged [audiowaveform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiowaveform). A large percentage of those tagged [waveform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/waveform) actually relate to audio waveforms and not other physical or abstract waveform representations.
Ideally, I think that all audio related questions should be tagged [audiowaveform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiowaveform) only.

How would we deal with this and make them easier to search?

Comment: I wonder how many `waveform` questions *don't* pertain to audio. Certainly some, but I would guess not many. If wanting to specify, when searching for *both*, a **logical and** search with the syntax `[audio] and [waveform]` seems to work.